# Wiped out email in actual server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, pop3

I recently connected Microsoft Outlook to my university email account. I loaded all the emails to outlook and used it for a couple of days. A few days later, I had to access the email from a remote location through the web interface and noticed that my inbox was cleared, and nothing was showing from the web client.

I did a few testing and noticed that whenever I load emails from outlook, it gets cleared from my inbox when accessed through the web. Is this normal? Is there a way to "reload" the emails from outlook to my university account?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you are accessing the email via POP with the setting to automatically delete the email when it is received by Outlook. If you have the ability switch from POP to IMAP. This will allow you to keep the same status at all locations. For example you can see quickly what has been read and what hasn't on any client.

EDIT: Oh yeah, if you add the IMAP client to the server while you have the pop still setup you can just drag the old emails from the POP account to the IMAP one. It will be slow, but you will have all of them on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your University has a POP account, and Outlook downloads everything from the server. Is it normal ? Yes that's how it is supposed to work.

> Is there a way to "reload" the emails from outlook to my university account? 
>   AFAIK, no.

Answer (score 1):

If you check outlooks "account settings" "advanced" tab you will find 
"leave a copy on the server" and 
"delete from the server when deleted from "deleted items"
Depending on your mail client the wording may be different but the functions are in 
every mail client.
Your *mail server* is on a *domain* this may mean that these functions are controlled
and greyed out.